# Is there any way to use the same fixture with parameterization and without parametrization?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

Is it possible to use the same fixture in cases where parametrization is needed and without parametrization?

Something like:

```
class Person:
    __init__(self, name, age)
      name = "Peter"
      age = 35
    
    @pytest.fixture(scope='function')
    def person(**kwargs):
       if request.node.callspec:
          name = request.node.callspec.params.get("name")
          age = request.node.callspec.params.get("age")
          return Person(name=name, age=age)
       else:
           return Person()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
import pytest


class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def person(request):
    parameter = getattr(request, "param", {})
    return Person(
        parameter.get("name", "Peter"),
        parameter.get("age", 35)
    )


@pytest.mark.parametrize("person", [{"name": "John", "age": 25}, {"name": "Max", "age": 31}], indirect=True)
def test_parametrized(person):
    print("\n", person.name, person.age)


def test_not_parametrized(person):
    print("\n", person.name, person.age)
```

Output is:

```
collecting ... collected 3 items

test_person.py::test_parametrized[person0] 
test_person.py::test_parametrized[person1] 
test_person.py::test_not_parametrized
PASSED                        [ 33%]John 25
PASSED                        [ 66%]Max 31
PASSED                        [100%]Peter 35
```

Comment: In general yes, it is the solution of my problem, but could you explain me indirect = True. When to use it ?

Comment: Sure. Basically `indirect` argument means that parameter names are actually fixtures and parameter values are passed to this fixtures as `request.param` values. Instead of passing `indirect=True` you also can specify which parameters should be considered as fixtures with params like this `indirect=['param_name']`. You can read more about indirect parametrization here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/example/parametrize.html#indirect-parametrization